# Asymmetrical Composition of images

Tags: tables, spacing, floats

[image: Figure 1]

I am desperately trying to arrange my images as in this sample figure for my paper and I am stuck.  Has anyone been able to do this successfully and could give me some pointers? It should be noted for my purpose the row height of image 1 is not equal to the height of row 2 or 3. Additionally, it is very important that these figures be together and cannot be floated. The text is referring to the caption.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

Note that only the fourth image and the caption need to be placed inside `minipage` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit "demo" option in real document
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}

\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig2}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig3}

\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig4}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{\fill}%
\begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
\caption[figure with long caption]{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long caption} 
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```